# Performing Comparisons "down" a table, not across rows

Tags: sql

I have a SQL problem that I don't have the vocabulary to explain very well.

Here is a simplified table. My goal is to identify groups where the Tax_IDs are not equal. In this case, the query should return groups 1 and 3.

```
Group   Line_ID     Tax_ID
1   1001        11
1   1002        13
2   1003        17
2   1004        17
3   1005        23
3   1006        29
```

I can easily perform comparisons across rows, however I do not know how to perform comparisons "down" a table (here is really where my vocabulary fails me). I.e. what is the syntax that will cause SQL to compare Tax_ID values within groups?

Any help appreciated,

- OB

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use `group by` with a `having` clause:

```
select "group"
from t
group by "group"
having min(tax_id) <> max(tax_id);
```

You can also phrase the `having` clause as:

```
having count(distinct tax_id) > 1;
```

However, `count(distinct)` is more expensive than just a `min()` or `max()`operation.

Comment: Gordon, thanks for the quick response. Your feedback makes sense. Can I extrapolate one step further and assume that comparisons "down" a table are generally performed by clever use of "group by" and "having" statements?

Comment: @user2577010 . . . Yes.  You will see that I often advocate that solution rather than doing complex self-joins.  Clearer SQL and often performs better (although not always).